# How to reference a maven dependency that does not follow the conventions

Tags: maven, vaadin

I am bound to use a module that is provided as a maven artifact that does not follow the conventions, in the sense that it contains *two* jar files: `artifactId-version.jar` and `artifactId-version-suffix.jar`. I have to reference *both* in my project, and I do not know how to do this. When I add a dependency to the artifact in my POM (in the usual way), I end up with only the first jar in my classpath. How do I get the second one, *-suffix.jar, on the classpath, too? (Without manually copying it into my project structure.)

Unfortunately, communication with the provider of the artifact is - well, difficult. Otherwise I would straight go and ask them first.

In case it matters: the artifact contains a Vaadin widgetset, and the suffix is actually "widgets". The first jar contains Java classes and XML files, the second one (with suffix) static web content: css, images, html files. It apparently accompanies a Vaadin theme (provided as another maven artifact). I browsed the Vaadin docs on whether this is a common way of delivering a widgetset, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suffix you mention is known as a *classifier* in [Maven terminology](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).

To get both dependencies, add another dependency to your POM (leave the one you have, too):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <classifier>suffix</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And I _thought_ I had browsed all the options inside the dependency element... Should have taken a break before. Thank you very much!